# How can a path differ between install version and while debugging?

Tags: c#, inno-setup

I have the following code that when used while debugging or using the release version of the solution works just fine, but when used with an Install version made from Inno Setup it returns the following error.

> ```
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
> HResult=0x80004005
> Message=Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
> Source=System
> ```

The error result from the following code at line compil start :

```
compil.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"innoFiles\\ISCC.exe";
compil.StartInfo.Arguments = strISSFile;
compil.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
compil.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compil.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
compil.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
compil.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
compil.ErrorDataReceived += Compil_DataReceived;
compil.OutputDataReceived += Compil_DataReceived;
compil.Exited += Compil_Exited;
compil.Start();
```

This application used to work just fine but I recently needed to make some changes to another part of the solution. The actual .iss file to make the install version of this solution has been lost hence me trying to make a new one.

Comment: I don't see how this **can** work. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` returns the path **without a trailing slash**, so the result of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"innoFiles\\ISCC.exe";` is going to be something like `c:\app_base_directoryinnoFiles\\ISCC.exe` which surely can't be right? So use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) instead of string addition.

Comment: @stuartd I did try to use Path.Combine just now. I arrive to the same result which is the solution works just fine in debug but when used after doing an install version with InnoSetup does not. The path I get from string addition is something like the following when looked in debug :
         c:\\appname\\something\\innoFiles\\ISCC.exe

Comment: So did you check what is the value of `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"innoFiles\\ISCC.exe")` and if that file exists (`File.Exists`)?